# BCP export to XML, opening XML gives error: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: sql-server, xml, bcp

I´m trying to export to XML format using BCP and the XML file is generated correctly but the actual content seems wrong. Can anyone help please?

When I try to open the XML in a browser I get the following error message:

> This page contains the following errors: error on line 1 at column 62:
>   Extra content at the end of the document

The SQL select that I'm using is:

```sql
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(1000)

SET @fileName = 'c:\fund_lib\test.xml'

USE PORT_APP_SQL

DROP TABLE ##temp;

WITH cte1
     AS (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(codigo))             AS code,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fecha, 120) AS date,
                precio                           AS NAV
         FROM   mpr_price_history
         WHERE  codigo IN( 'LU0038743380', 'LU0086913042', 'LU0265291665', 'LU0098860363',
                           'LU0128525689', 'LU0121204944', 'CZ0008474780', 'LU0363630376',
                           'LU0372180066', 'LU0271663857', 'LU0271663774', 'LU0363630707', 'LU0313643024' ))
SELECT *
INTO   ##temp
FROM   cte1

SET @sqlStr = 'select * from ##temp  order by code, date desc FOR XML RAW (''code'');'
-- Save XML records to a file:
SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName
              + ' -S "MPR01\SQLEXPRESS"  -T -w'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd
```

And this is the error message if I open it in Firefox ( sorry is in Spanish).

[error message seems to be at the end of each line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQfci.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your whole query can be simplified... No need for a CTE or a temp table...

**attention** The solution for your problem is - probably! - the missing root node, as mentioned by `@TT.`. If adding a root node solves your problem, please do not accept my answer (although you might vote it up, if you like it :-)  ).

Your problem might be bound to a mix of encodings. If your output includes special characters, there could be some problems when you mix 8-byte encoding (`VARCHAR`) and the output with option `-w`. Therefore I put this all in `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

My suggestion to get things slim:

```
USE PORT_APP_SQL;

DECLARE @fileName NVARCHAR(50) = 'c:\fund_lib\test.xml';
DECLARE @cmd      NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cmd = 
N'SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(codigo))             AS code
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fecha, 120)   AS [date]
      ,precio                             AS NAV
FROM   mpr_price_history
WHERE  codigo IN( ''LU0038743380'', ''LU0086913042'', ''LU0265291665'', ''LU0098860363'',
                  ''LU0128525689'', ''LU0121204944'', ''CZ0008474780'', ''LU0363630376'',
                  ''LU0372180066'', ''LU0271663857'', ''LU0271663774'', ''LU0363630707'', ''LU0313643024'' )
ORDER BY code,[date] DESC
FOR XML RAW(''code''),ROOT(''root'');'

-- Save XML records to a file:
SET @cmd = N'bcp "' + @cmd + N'" queryout ' + @fileName
              + N' -S "MPR01\SQLEXPRESS"  -T -w'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because the XML doesn't have a root path. This example based on your script should produce XML for which the browser doesn't complain:

```sql
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(1000);

SET @fileName = 'c:\temp\test.xml';

SELECT *
INTO   ##temp
FROM   (VALUES('LU0038743380',GETDATE(),1),
              ('LU0086913042',GETDATE(),2),
              ('LU0265291665',GETDATE(),3),
              ('LU0098860363',GETDATE(),4)) AS cte1(fecha,[date],nav);

SET @sqlStr = 'select (select * from ##temp FOR XML RAW(''code''),TYPE) FOR XML PATH(''data'');'

-- Save XML records to a file:
SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName
              + ' -S '+@@SERVERNAME+'  -T -w';

EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd;

DROP TABLE ##temp;
```

Comment: @Sue Then your question does not have enough details for us to help you. You might want to include the generated XML verbatim in your question, or write a sample standalone script (i.e. not dependent on any tables in your database) that shows the problem.

Comment: @Sue The error you have included is exactly the error I solved in the answer I posted, while you claim that you still get the same error. Run the script in my answer again and open the result in a browser (new page). I tested in FireFox, the generated XML does not result in an error. If I apply the direct `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH RAW...` as in your question, indeed I am getting the exact same error as you get. If you want to open XML in a browser, it requires a root node. That is exactly what I did in the sample script: make sure the generated XML has a root node (`data` in this case).

Comment: Although I think you are rigth, that the missing root-node is the error's source, I'd suggest simply to add a `ROOT`-clause to the original query:  `... FOR XML RAW('code'),ROOT('root')`.

Comment: @Sue, If you still get the problem, just try to open your XML-file within an editor and add `<root>` as first line and `</root>` at the very end manually. I'm quite sure, that your browser will be able to open this with a valid `<root>`-node...

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks for the hint Shnugo :)

Answer (score 0):

I have ran your code with small alterations with no errors.
It seems the issue is with your data.
Look for special XML characters.